# WP_Error Ajax Search

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am using WordPress for my website and using woocommerce for selling.
When I search, I get an error by as listed below.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in
>   /home1/......../public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1025

I am using plugin, Contact Form 7, Envato WordPress Toolkit,
Indeed Smart PopUp, LayerSlider WP, Nav Menu Roles, Premium SEO pack - Wordpress Plugin, Rich Snippets WordPress Plugin by WP-Buddy, Shopme Custom Content Types and Taxonomies, Slider Revolution, Ultimate WooCommerce Brands PRO, Woo Sale Revolution:Flash Sale + Dynamic Discounts, WooCommerce, WPBakery Visual Composer, YITH Live Chat Premium, YITH WooCommerce Ajax Search, YITH WooCommerce Compare, YITH WooCommerce Multi Vendor Premium, YITH WooCommerce Share For Discounts Premium, YITH WooCommerce Wishlist.

Can I have solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

Back up your your current DB and import an older version when the site was working normally. Re install WP and all the plugins. Make sure you install a fresh copy from WP.  Let me know.